# On Linux, why does directory tab completion add a \ to a path starting with ~

Tags: linux, command-line

On my work scientific linux 6.2 machine, I often start typing in a directory like below and use tab completion to finish it:

```
~/mydir
```

But when I hit tab, it becomes e.g.

```
\~/mydirectory/
```

With an extra forward slash at the start. Why is this, and can I prevent it? It's a pain because using cd etc. doesn't work with the extra slash, I have to start from the actual home directory which is something like

```
/home/username/
```

On these PCs.

### Edit

Actually this problem did not show up for every directory, only one particular one, which I didn't realise when I asked. The cause of the problem is given in my answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had accidentally created a directory named `~` in my home directory. This was the root cause of the problems. Removing this solved them.

Answer (score 2):

Linux does not apply any tab completion. The shell does.

The boxes have a mis-configured completion system, or perhaps they mis-apply, for example zsh completion to bash or vice versa.

1. Try starting another shell (bash, zsh) and sourcing /etc/profile* for that shell
2. log in without a profile. ssh host.com bash --noprofile --norc

This will help you figure out where the problem lies. I am confident that the problem is in the setup files (profile) of the host or user and that this is not an issue with the shell.

Comment: Thanks, at least you have confirmed that this should not work this way, and is probably a setup problem I can contact the sysadmin about. As you might have guessed, I'm a relatively new Linux user. I will forward your reply to IT now that I know the problem is not me at least. I'll mark this as the answer if they agree. Until then, I would give you an upvote, but don't have enough rep on this site yet.

Comment: The real problem is that I had a directory name `~` in my home directory. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [blog post](http://linux-bsd-sharing.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/tip-enable-bash-completion-on-centos-62.html) about installing an utility called [bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org) it's more powerful than the default tab completion code and it's more flexible.

The *command completion* by the way

Alternatively, When you issue the command:

```
cd
```

Without parameters you will cd to your home directory, after that you can simply start to type:

```
mydir
```

And when you hit tab, the autocomplete will turn it to

```
mydirectory
```

Comment: Thanks for replying though, this is a work PC (or rather a network of many work PCs), so I can't really install whatever I want on it. Your workaround will work for the specific case of cd, but I don't always want to have to change directory to do this.